Does sealing low voltage high current fuse box from air exchange affect the current where the fuse blows?
I have a (Victron Energy) low voltage high current fuse box, which is intended for mega fuses such as 80A, 100A, 125A.
Unfortunately, the fuse box has quite large holes where the thick cables go in, and allows touching the metal terminals of the wires. While a short circuit is improbable, it's not impossible and I would like to seal these holes with hot melt glue.
However, sealing the holes makes the fuse box mostly sealed from air exchange.
Fuses blow by temperature, and anything that reduces its cooling could theoretically affect the temperature where the fuse blows.
Does sealing the fuse box from air exchange markedly change the temperature where the fuse blows, or can I safely block the air holes?
I was thinking that maybe the thick copper cables would work well to conduct the heat of the fuse away, and the small air holes inside the fuse box maybe don't cool as effectively as the thick copper cables on either side of the fuse box. So the effect on the fuse temperature might be minimal, if I block the air holes.
Of course, I have to ensure the hot melt glue doesn't prevent me from opening the fuse box later.


Does sealing the fuse box from air exchange markedly change the temperature where the fuse blows,

Temperature does indeed affect a fuse's blowing current.
The spec sheet of the Mega fuses has this chart that show the significant reduction in the blow current when going from room temperature to 100 °C.

{Source: LittelFuse}
Which is why fuse manufacturers specify the fuse mounting and wiring to the fuse holder.

can I safely block the air holes?

You can, but, to avoid nuisance fuse blows, you must use fuses rated at a higher current, or you must cool the cabinet, or you must provide a path for the heat to transfer from the fuse holder to the cool outer ambient.
